# A Deleted file loading with a url without www in it. how to get rid of that file being accessed?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, no-www

My website is loading same files with www and without www. I just deleted the file from file manager and its showing 404 which is fine but a different version of it is loading

`https://ospreyhomes.ae/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png` (Delete but loading over without www domain)

`https://www.ospreyhomes.ae/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png` (Deleted - 404)

How can i get rid of the https://ospreyhomes.ae/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png being accessed on internet. i have already deleted the file

Same things goes with these 2 files. File deleted but being accessed with url without www

https://ospreyhomes.ae/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png

https://www.ospreyhomes.ae/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png

Comment: Clear your browser cache! (But since you appear to be 301 redirecting non-www to www, I don't see how you are even accessing the apex domain?)

Comment: Remove the logo link in Customizer. You have deleted the image file but logo image link is still there in Customizer Settings So just make required changes in Customizer options OR theme options.

Answer (score 0):

Its almost happen to any file when you have cdn cache service enable like cloudflare. Make sure you clear your browser cache. Try F5. Even not working,Then try a proxy browser to see real-time status of file or disable cloudflare while editing files.
From my side,i see your file has been deleted.